# Element ignores jQuery if triggered repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm making a website responsive and so far it works reasonably well, a problem I am having at the moment though, is that if I repeatedly and quickly change the window size it seems to ignore the jQuery. When this happens an element that is supposed to "display:none;" when conditions are met is left on the page.

The css is simple:

```
body:after{display:none; content:"default";}
@media only all and (max-width: 800px){
    body:after{content:"tablet";}
}
```

and the jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var currentSize = "default";
    var lazyLayout = _.debounce(function(e) {
    }, 300, true);
    $(window).resize(lazyLayout,function() {
            var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
            /* Ridiculous thing to deal with inconsistent returning of 
            value from query. Some browsers have quotes some don't */
            size = size.replace(/"/g, "");
            size = size.replace(/'/g, "");
            if (size != currentSize) {
                if (size == 'tablet') {
                    var count = $('#mobileNav').length;
                    if (count < 1) {
                        var data = {
                        dataType: "HTML",
                        action: 'nav_media_query',
                        nonce: myAjax.nonce
                    };
                    $.post( myAjax.url, data, function( data ) {
                        $('#content-wrapper').removeClass('col-4-5');
                        $('#trending-Container').addClass('mobileNavStyle');
                        $('#trending-Container').append(data);
                        });
                    currentSize = 'tablet';
                    }

                }  
                if(size == 'default') {
                    $('#mobileNav').remove();
                    currentSize = 'default';
                }
            }
    }).resize();

});//end function
```

This checks to see if a media query has been loaded but looking for the content attribute, it then fires off an ajax request and loads some wordpress php in to an element.

It works perfectly if I slowly resize the window, but if I quickly and repeatedly adjust the window, it breaks.

Is there some jQuery function I can use to stop it from breaking?

**Edit: I have updated my code to add _.js debounce method, this should help limit the ajax requests. The problem of the element not being removed after the requirements are no longer met still persists though.**

Comment: You desperately need to use throttling or debouncing if you're going to send an ajax request on resize or scrolling events. There's throttling and debouncing methods in underscore.js

Comment: @ahren Thanks, will applying throttling or debouncing stop the problem? I will definitely apply it but curious as to whether the problem will stop.

Comment: It will most definitely help - basically, most modern browsers will fire the resize and scrolling events so rapidly you're sending hundreds if not thousands of ajax requests, and it kills either your server or the client trying to handle all of the requests. Especially since it's async in nature, so you're not guaranteed to get the responses in the same order that you sent them.

Comment: I noticed that when I was testing it out with a ++ var console.log(), you're right, thanks. Good job I didn't make it go live that would have been bad ha.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a function called within the resize function that waits. Im not quite sure if it will work but try to use the delay function in jquery in this sort of way:

```
setTimeout(showpanel, 1000)

function showpanel() {     
  //Code that you want to execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Undescore.js solved the problem, I just didn't apply the function properly.

Here's the result.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var currentSize = "default";
    $(window).resize(_.debounce(function(){
    var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
            /* Ridiculous thing to deal with inconsistent returning of 
            value from query. Some browsers have quotes some don't */
            size = size.replace(/"/g, "");
            size = size.replace(/'/g, "");
            if (size != currentSize) {
                if (size == 'tablet') {
                    var count = $('#mobileNav').length;
                    if (count < 1) {
                        var data = {
                        dataType: "HTML",
                        action: 'nav_media_query',
                        nonce: myAjax.nonce
                    };
                    $.post( myAjax.url, data, function( data ) {
                        $('#content-wrapper').removeClass('col-4-5');
                        $('#trending-Container').addClass('mobileNavStyle');
                        $('#trending-Container').append(data);
                        });
                    currentSize = 'tablet';
                    }

                }  
                if(size == 'default') {
                    $('nav').remove('#mobileNav');
                    $('#content-wrapper').addClass('col-4-5');
                    $('#trending-Container').removeClass('mobileNavStyle');
                    currentSize = 'default';
                }
            }
    },200));

});//end function
```